# solving the congruence $ax \equiv b \mod m $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here on this [pdf](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec4.pdf) on  page no $5$ it is stated that

> Let $g = (a, m)$. Then there is a solution to $ax \equiv b \mod m$ if and only
>   if $g|b$. If it has solutions, then it has exactly $g$ solutions $\mod m$.

I do not understand the proof that it has exactly $g$ solutions. How we conclude the second last and last sentence on the pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_0$ is one solution, then $x_1 = x_0 + m/g$ is another. So is $x_2 = x_0 + 2m/g$, and so on. Modulo $m$ there are exactly $g$ different congruence classes hit by the different $x_n$. Therefore there are *at least* $g$ solutions.

As for why there cannot be more than $g$ solutions, try solving $ay \equiv 0 \pmod m$ first. Then notice that any two solutions to $ax \equiv b$ must have a difference equal to one of those $y$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252251/number-of-solutions-of-ax-equiv-b-mod-n?rq=1) question is more or less identical. See if you can understand any of that.