# $x \equiv a \pmod{\!n}\iff x \equiv a\,$ or $\, a + n \pmod{\!2n}$

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

My rationale was the following. If $n$ is even, then

$$n \mid x - a \implies n \mid x - a - n \implies n \mid \frac{1}{2} (x - a - n) \implies 2n \mid x - a - n  $$

so $x \equiv a + n \pmod{2n}$. On the other hand, if $n$ is odd, $(n:2)=1$. Hence the Chinese remainder theorem guarantees that the linear congruence system

$$\begin{cases} x \equiv a \pmod{n} \\ x \equiv a \pmod{2} \end{cases}$$

has a unique solution modulo $2n$. We know the solution is $x \equiv a(2+n) \mod{2n}$, which is congruent to $n \equiv a(2 - n) \pmod{2n}$.

Given that $n$ is odd, $(2+n:2-n)=1$. Therefore $x \equiv a \pmod{2n}$.

Is this more or less correct?

Comment: Something is fishy here. Take $n=4, x =3, a = 3$. Your proof says that since $n$ is even, 3 is congruent to 7 mod 8, which is not correct. Can you find the error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite see what you are doing. Let
$$ x-a = tn \; . $$

If $t$ is even, let $t = 2 s,$ so
$$ x-a = s(2n) $$
so $$x \equiv a \pmod {2n}$$

If $t$ is odd, write $t = 2r + 1,$
 so $$  x-a = tn = (2r+1)n = 2rn + n \; ,   $$
$$ x-a = r(2n) + n, $$
$$   x= a + n + r (2n)  $$
$$x \equiv a +n \pmod {2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\!\phantom{.} x\equiv a\pmod{\!n} \!\iff\!\! \overbrace{x = a \!+\! n\:\!\color{#0af}k}^{\large\text{for some } \color{#0af}k\ \in\ \Bbb Z}\!\!\! \iff\!\! \begin{align} &x ={{a\!+\!n\overbrace{(\color{#0a0}0\!+\!2j)}^{k\rm\ is\ \color{#0a0}{even}}}}\equiv a\!+\!\color{#0a0}0\,n\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!2n}\\[.3em] 
&x = {{a\!+\!n\underbrace{(\color{#c00}1\!+\!2j)}_{\!k\rm\ is\ \color{#c00}{odd}}}}\equiv \:\!a\!+\!\color{#c00}1\:\!n\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!2n} \end{align}$

$ $ using the *Division Algorithm*  $\,(k\div 2)\,$ to write  $\ \color{#0af}k = r\! +\! 2j\ $ for $\, r = \color{#0a0}0\,$ or $\,\color{#c00}1$

---

**Or**  $\!\bmod 2n\!:\  kn \overset{\rm\color{#c00}D}\equiv (\overbrace{k\bmod 2}^{\large \color{#0a0}0\,\ {\rm or}\,\ \color{#c00}1})\:\!n\equiv \color{#0a0}0, \color{#c00}n\,$ $\overset{\!\!+\, a}\Rightarrow a\!+\!kn\equiv a\!+\!\color{#0a0}0,a\!+\!\color{#c00}n\ $
& $\:\!\ \bmod\:\! dn_{\phantom{|_|}}\!\!\!\!:\:\!\ kn \overset{\rm\color{#c00}D}\equiv (k\bmod d)\:\!n\equiv \color{#0a0}0n, \color{#c00}1n,2n,\ldots,(\color{#0af}d\!-\!1)n,\,$ takes $\,\color{#0af}d\,$ values,
where we invoked $\:\!\small\rm\color{#c00}D=$ [mod Distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242).

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295406/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252346/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) $\ \ $