# number of possible integers in residue class $p^r$ congruent to an integer mod $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $\lambda$ be a given integer and $p$ is a prime and integer $r$.

In this case, for $\lambda$ why are there $p^{r-1}$ number of possible $\mu$ from the residue class $p^r$ that satisfies $\mu \equiv \lambda$ mod $p$ and $p^{r-2}$ number of possible $\mu$ that satisfies $\mu \equiv \lambda$ mod $p^2$?

Now I want to show this because I want the result that for any given integers $(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_r)$, there are $\Pi_{j=1}^{r-1}p^{r-j}=p^{r(r-1)/2}$ different vectors $(\mu_1,\dots, \mu_r)$ modulo $p^r$ such that
$$\mu_j \equiv \lambda_j\; \text{mod} \;p^j \; \forall 1\le j \le r.$$

**Edit** This question was written incorrectly so I've edited it and lulu's comments have solved the reasoning.

Comment: Not following.  Why does it matter if $p>r$?  And $\mu \equiv \lambda \pmod {p^r}\implies \mu \equiv \lambda \pmod {p}$ so why list the redundant condition?

Comment: I suggest:  provide an explicit example of what exactly it is you are trying to count.

Comment: @lulu $p>r$ is irrelevant for this it was just a part of assumption of the Lemma I am trying to prove. I've provided the context in which I need this result. If this is still unclear I will state the whole lemma.

Comment: So, delete the irrelevant assumption.  And...why impose redundant conditions?  If $p^r$ divides $n$ then $p^j$ divides $n$ for all $j<r$, so what are you saying?  Again, I suggest providing an explicit numerical example of whatever it is you are trying to describe.

Comment: To stress: what you have written is very unclear.  It's not even clear what $\mu$ is supposed to be.  If $\mu$ can be any integer then, presumably, there are infinitely many $\mu$ congruent to a given integer mod whatever you like.  If $\mu$ is meant to be a residue $\pmod {p^r}$ then there is only one choice of $\mu$ congruent to a given integer $\pmod {p^r}$.  But maybe $\mu$ is something else altogether?  As I say, an explicit example illustrating the count you have in mind should clarify your meaning.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post for clarity.  Examples are always a good idea.

Comment: @lulu Okay thank you for the clarification. This was all a misunderstanding of the statement from me. So I believe what is meant here is that in the residue class $p^r$ there are at most $p^{r-1}$ numbers $\mu$ that is congruent to a given $\lambda$ mod $p$ and $p^{r-2}$ numbers of $\mu$ that is congruent to a given $\lambda$ mod $p^2$ and so on. Does this make sense?

Comment: @lulu so for example if $r=2, p=3$ and $\lambda_1 = 7 , \lambda_2=12$ then there are three $\mu_1=1,4,7$ and one $\mu_2=3$ choices that makes sense.

Comment: $p=4$ is not a prime.  And, as a general rule, it's best to avoid $2$ as a choice of a "random" prime.  Lots of things that are true for odd primes work poorly for $2$.

Comment: @lulu That was a typo from me sorry. Anyways your pointing out of my mistakes made everything clear. I will just close this question sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: All that said:  There are $p^{r-1}$ multiples of $p$ $\pmod {p^r}$.  They are $\{0, 1\times p, 2\times p, \cdots,( p^{r-1}-1)\times p\}$.  I think this is what you are asking, no?

Comment: @lulu I think that is right. So if $\lambda_1$ is a given integer then it will be congruent to some number between 0 and p-1. And we have $p^{r-1}$ multiples which will be in the residue class mod $p^r$ and those are as you stated in the parentheses.

Comment: Yes, that's my point.  I think that's what you have in mind here, no?

Comment: I don't follow your question, but with regard to the query in the title: Keeping to the convention that a number modulo $q$ is smaller than $q$ (are you using that understanding in your question?), numbers of the form $kp^r+j$ have residues $\bmod p^r$ that are larger than $p$ when $j>p$. The only numbers that have equal residues both $\bmod p$ and $\bmod p^r$ have the form $kp^r+j$ for $j\le p$. Of course, there are infinitely many of these because $k$ can have any integer value.

Comment: @KeithBackman Yes the question was incorrect and the discussion with lulu has solved it.

Comment: The reduction map from $\!\bmod \color{#c00}kn\,$ to $\!\bmod n\,$ [is $\,\color{#c00}k$-to-$1.\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295406/242) Here $\,nk = p^r,\ n = p^2$ so $\,\color{#c00}k = p^r/p^2 = p^{r-2}\ \ $