# Why is there a single solution to this system of congruences?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am studying the following problem, in which I don't see why one of the congruences has a single solution:

> What is the number of solutions $(\bmod m n)$ for the equations $x=a(\bmod m)$ and $x=b(\bmod n)$ where $\operatorname{gcd}(m, n)=\operatorname{gcd}(a, m)=\operatorname{gcd}(b, n)=d ?$ **Answer:** $d$. There is a single solution for $y=a / d(\bmod m / d)$ and $y=b / d(\bmod n / d)$, and $x=$ $y d+i m n / d(\bmod m n)$ for $i \in\{0, \ldots, d-1\}$ satisfies $x=a(\bmod m)$ and $x=b(\bmod n)$ as $m n / d=0$ $(\bmod m)$ and $m n / d=0(\bmod n)$. Any $z=0 \bmod m$ and $z=0(\bmod n)$ implies that $z$ is a multiple of $m n / d$, these are the only solutions.

I am not seeing why there is a single solution for $y=a / d\pmod {m / d}$ and $y=b / d\pmod {n / d}$, as $m \over d$ and $n \over d$ don't seem necessarily coprime, as they could have other factors in common besides $d$, so eliminating $d$ doesn't seem to put us in a position where we could use CRT to conclude a unique solution here. What basis do we have to conclude that there exists a single solution here?

Comment: See the uniqueness part of the proof of [General Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: @billDubuque I read the uniqueness part which showed how the solution was unique in mod $mn \over d$; however I am actually not seeing how to apply it here as I believe $y$ is unique in mod $mn$ instead. How could I use this argument to show $y$ is unique here? I believe the difference between the post you showed and the one I have are the constraints on $a,b$ having gcd $d$ with their moduli here.

Comment: @BillDubuque actually, is the argument that $m \over d$ and $n \over d$ are actually coprime, as $d$ is gcd so dividing through renders them coprime? So by CRT there is solution?

Comment: Yes $\,(m,n)=d\Rightarrow (m/d,n/d)=1\,$ [by the gcd distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213430/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque actually, if we use CRT on the basis of $m \over d$ and $n \over d$ being coprime, then we could only say $y$ is unique mod $mn \over d^2$; which argument would we use to show $y$ is unique mod $mn$, which seems to be the intended modulus in which $y$ is said to be unique in the solution I presented?

Comment: $x/d\equiv c\pmod{\!mn/\color{#c00}{d^2}}\!\!\!\overset{\times\ \color{#c00}d\!}\iff  x\equiv cd\pmod{\!mn/{\color{#c00}d}} \ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque would this not imply that there are $d^2$ solutions in mod $mn$ then? Because there are $d$ possibilities for what $yd$ could be in mod $mn$ by the statement you just commented, and $d$ possibilities for $i$ in $y d+i m n / d(\bmod m n)$?

Comment: A residue $\,a\bmod m\,$ maps to $\,\color{darkorange}d\,$ values $\!\bmod \color{darkorange}dm,\,$ i.e.

$$\quad\ \begin{align} x \equiv a\!\!\!\pmod{\! m}\,  &\equiv\, \{\, a + k\:\!m\}_{\,\large  0\le k<\color{darkorange}d}\!\!\pmod{\!dm}\\[.3em] 
&\equiv\, \{a,\,\ a\! +\! m,\,\ldots,\, a\! +\! (\color{darkorange}d\!-\!1)m\}
\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: which is true because $\ k\:\!m\bmod dm =\, (\color{#c00}{k\bmod d})\, m\ $ by MDL, and the RHS  takes *exactly* $\,d\,$ values $\!\bmod dm,\,$ i.e. $\,\color{#c00}0m,\, \color{#c00}1m,\, \color{#c00}2m, \ldots, (\color{#c00}{d\!-\!1})m.\,$ Here MDL = [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242).

Comment: e.g.

$$ \overbrace{3x\equiv 6\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!12}}^{{\rm\large cancel}\ \ \Large (3,12)\,=\,\color{darkorange}3}\iff x\equiv 2\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!4}\,\equiv\, \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\overbrace{\{2,6,10\}}^{\qquad\ \ \Large\{ 2\,+\,4k\}_{\ \Large 0\le k< \color{darkorange}3}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{darkorange}3\cdot 4}\qquad $$  See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3295406/242).